# Update SQL Database from GridView TemplateField DropDownLists

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

This has been torturing me for the past 2 days and I am desperately hoping that someone can provide some guidance.  I really have no clue where I am going wrong so anything anyone can do to help would be absolutely fantastic.

SQLDataSource1 is a View. It grabs the PKs from the fields from tbl_Job and translates to names.  Also grabs the keys as well.
SQLOrigin is a datasource for tbl_origin

[image: SQL View]
[image: tbl_Job]
[image: tbl_origin]

I have the Edit button enabled via `CommandField` so that users can edit a row.

These are my `SqlDataSources`:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SQLDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:HSEProjRegConnectionString1 %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM v_job_details WHERE Project_ID=@id" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [tbl_Job] SET [Job_Origin_ID]=@originID,[Job_Department_ID]=@departmentID,[Job_Priority_ID]=@priorityID,[Job_Status_ID]=@statusID WHERE [Job_ID]=@Job_ID"
    OnUpdated="SQLDataSource1_Updated">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="id" Type="Int32" QueryStringField="id" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="originID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="departmentID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="priorityID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="statusID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Job_ID" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SQLOrigin" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:HSEProjRegConnectionString1 %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tbl_origin] WHERE Active = 1"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I use `TemplateFields` and `ItemTemplates` to display the contents of a table in a `DropDownList`.  This is the code for that is below.  Please note that I did not add all the TemplateFields to save space.  They are identical except for field references.

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" />
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="False"
    DataSourceID="SQLDataSource1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Job_ID">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Job ID" DataField="Job_ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Reference/Origin">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SQLOrigin" DataTextField="Name"
                    DataValueField="origin_ID" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("origin_ID") %>' Width="150px"
                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("origin") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="true" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And this is what I have in my Code Behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = sender as DropDownList;
        if (ddl == null) { return; }
        GridViewRow gvr = ddl.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
        if (gvr == null) { return; }

        SQLDataSource1.UpdateParameters["originID"].DefaultValue = GridView1.DataKeys[gvr.RowIndex]["Job_ID"].ToString();
    }

    protected void SQLDataSource1_Updated(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Exception == null) && e.AffectedRows.Equals(1))
        {
            Label1.Text = "Data successfully updated!";

            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

When I hit `Edit` in the `GridView`, I update ALL fields and select `Update` and get this error:

```
The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_tbl_Job_tbl_status".     The conflict occurred in database "HSE_proj", table "dbo.tbl_status", column 'Status_ID'.
The statement has been terminated.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_tbl_Job_tbl_status". The conflict occurred in database "HSE_proj", table "dbo.tbl_status", column 'Status_ID'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

If I try to only update 1 field, I get the below error.  In the below case, I was trying to modify the `ORIGIN` field and the `DEPARTMENT` field was right next to it.  The error details changes depending on which column I am trying to modify, but the error itself is the same.

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Job_Department_ID', table 'HSE_proj.dbo.tbl_Job'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
The statement has been terminated.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Job_Department_ID', table 'HSE_proj.dbo.tbl_Job'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
The statement has been terminated.
```

*EDIT* When I added `AutoPostback="true"` to the `DropDownLists`, I started getting the below error.  I just don't understand where the NULL value is coming from.  I will insert a breakpoint and see if I can see what is going wrong.

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Job_Origin_ID', table 'HSE_proj.dbo.tbl_Job'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
The statement has been terminated.
```

*EDIT 2*
Modified the Code Behind to the following.  When I insert a breakpoint and follow it through, it is picking up the values that it should but it is still giving me a `NULL` error.

```
    protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = sender as DropDownList;
        if (ddl == null) { return; }
        GridViewRow gvr = ddl.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
        if (gvr == null) { return; }

        DropDownList ddlOrigin = (DropDownList)sender;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)ddlOrigin.NamingContainer;

        Control control = row.FindControl("DropDownList2");

        if (ddlOrigin != null)
        {
            SQLDataSource1.UpdateParameters["originID"].DefaultValue = ddlOrigin.SelectedValue;
            SQLDataSource1.UpdateParameters["updateID"].DefaultValue = GridView1.DataKeys[gvr.RowIndex]["Job_ID"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

*EDIT 3*
Still trying to get this to work.  Thought about trying to obtain the values in `Page_Load` and had a `using` method in there to add parameters with values, but I couldn't make that work.  The code didn't make any sense so I scrapped.  All examples I can find online all point toward using `OnSelectedIndexChanged` and `AutoPostBack="true"` which when using breakpoints is actually returning the values it should, but for some reason when I try to update the table with those values it is still saying NULL.

I might not be reading this correctly.  In `Locals`, if I go into `this` navigate to the `SQLDataSource`, `UpdateParameters`, `Non-Public members`, `base`, `_collectionItems`, I see the Parameters I set up in the code and `originID` has the correct PK from `tbl_origin`.  I am not overly experienced in debugging and to me, I wonder if a problem could be that they are in `Non-Public members` meaning that it is possible that the `UpdateCommand` can't access the values even though the code did find them?  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Hey, your DropDownList does not have the `AutoPostback = true`. If you don't have this the `OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged"` won't fire.

Comment: Thanks, I made that modification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_tbl_Job_tbl_status".     The conflict occurred in database "HSE_proj", table "dbo.tbl_status", column 'Status_ID'.
The statement has been terminated
```

What this basically means is that this update would cause there to be a FOREIGN Key Violation. There are restrictions on your database that for every item in the table you are working on an item must exist in another specific table. In this case `StatusID`

In the second part of your question:

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Job_Department_ID', table 'HSE_proj.dbo.tbl_Job'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
The statement has been terminated.
```

I would assume this has something to do with nullable fields. You cant have certain fields null so its evidently getting some values that are nothing. I would put a breakpoint in their and step through it to see what is getting called when you update.

Comment: First issue I am coming across is that my C# methods are not returning the value they should be.  The Selected Value is `"1"` when the row ID I am trying to modify is 28.  I am finding this horribly confusing.  lol

Comment: LOL! Yeah the SQL errors you are getting are telling you the story. Its not getting all the data it needs to complete the SQL command.

Comment: Took me a while but I finally figured it out.  Well mostly.  I slightly changed how I was doing it and then was able to get the SQL issues resolved.